# How to get the generic type of a generic class in JAVA

Tags: java, generics

I have a class A

```
class A<V>{}
```

and class B extends A

```
class B extends A<V>{}
```

and class C have generic B, and I want to know the V from B

It is possible to do like this

```
class C<P extends B<V>,V>{
   P mP;
   V mV;
}
```

But since generic type of P(i.e. class B) knows it must have a V(i.e. class A), I do not have to specify V to know what V is when I create an object of C.
I tried code like this but this is not valid

```
class C<P<V> extends B>{
   P mP;
   V mV;
}
```

Comment: If you're trying to get the type that parameterizes V, then that's hard to do in Java.  (If you're not, then I've misunderstood your question.)  You can download a library that will do this for you, however these libraries have to do a lot of work and they are slow.  The best idea is to work around this so it is not necessary to know the type of V.  Design the code differently.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that

```
class B extends A<V>{}
```

is a typo as here, `V` had to be an *actual type*, e.g. a `class`, `enum` or `interface` with the name `V` that must be in scope, which must not be confused with `A`’s type parameter `V`, and since `B` would not be generic, `P extends B<V>` should not compile.

So I assume

```
class B<V> extends A<V>{}
```

In that setup,

```
class C<P extends B<V>,V>{
   P mP;
   V mV;
}
```

would be a valid declaration, introducing a new type parameter `V` and defining the relationship to `B`. In this situation, you can’t omit `V`. If you were not using `V` within `C`, you could use `class C<P extends B<?>>` to denote that you don’t care about the actual type parameter of `B`.

But since you are using `V`, it must be declared. This might be annoying to the users of `C` that wish to have `V` to be implied by the actual type they use for `P`, but there is no way around it in Java.

The closest you can get, would be to separate the class into a front-end class with a single type parameter and a specialized implementation class which can be instantiated without specifying the type arguments when using the “diamond operator”, i.e.

```
abstract class FrontEnd<T> {
    // define the API
}
class C<P extends B<V>, V> extends FrontEnd<P> {
   P mP;
   V mV;
}

…

FrontEnd<ActualSubtypeOfB> myObj = new C<>();
```

but unfortunately that would imply that the API of `FrontEnd` can not refer to `V`, so this is rarely sufficient.